# Item coupon dimension not visible in Looker Studio

Tags: dimension, coupon

I would like to ask you why I can not see dimension of Item Coupon in Looker studio.

In GA4 explore report I can see this dimension, but not in Looker studio:

[image]
[image]

The main goal is to find an answer "How many times were products view in item list with coupon?".

Thank you